# setInputFiles gives error on antd upload component

Tags: antd, e2e-testing, playwright

My application is using [antd upload element](https://ant.design/components/upload/).

Using Playwright, I am writing a test where I upload files. The selector I am using is:

```js
await page.locator('button:has-text("Click To Upload")').setInputFiles(`${filePath}/${filename1}`);
```

I am able to successfully grab the `Click To Upload` button and call click(), so I know the selector is correct. However, if I try the api [setInputFiles](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-set-input-files) I get

```
frame.setInputFiles: Error: Node is not an HTMLInputElement

=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for selector "button:has-text("Click To Upload")"
  selector resolved to visible <button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-default"></button>
============================================================
```

Looking at the html of the element I see:

```html
<span>
   <span class="">
      <div class="ant-upload ant-upload-select ant-upload-select-text">
         <span tabindex="0" class="ant-upload" role="button">
            <input type="file" accept="" multiple="" style="display: none;">
            <button type="button" class="ant-btn ant-btn-default" ant-click-animating-without-extra-node="false">
               <span role="img" aria-label="upload" class="anticon anticon-upload">
                  <svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="upload" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
                     <path d="M400 317.7h73.9V656c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h60c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V317.7H624c6.7 0 10.4-7.7 6.3-12.9L518.3 163a8 8 0 00-12.6 0l-112 141.7c-4.1 5.3-.4 13 6.3 13zM878 626h-60c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v154H214V634c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8h-60c-4.4 0-8 3.6-8 8v198c0 17.7 14.3 32 32 32h684c17.7 0 32-14.3 32-32V634c0-4.4-3.6-8-8-8z"></path>
                  </svg>
               </span>
               <span>Click To Upload</span>
            </button>
         </span>
      </div>
      <div class="ant-upload-list ant-upload-list-text"></div>
   </span>
</span>
```

I have to be able to use `setInputFiles` because it takes the relative path automatically. Any ideas what is wrong and how I can make the `setInputFiles` work?

Comment: I'm running into the exact same issue. Have you found a solution since then ? The answer below is not working (at least for me)

Comment: I would check your playwright version if my solution is not working since it worked for me. Also, make sure your using a async function since there are awaits.

Answer (score 3):

From reading documentation, `setInputFiles` requires a input element.

However, if input is not available because it is dynamic you can use this method:

```js
      let [fileChooser] = await Promise.all([
        page.waitForEvent('filechooser'),
        page.locator('button:has-text("Click To Upload")').click(),
      ]);

      await fileChooser.setFiles([`${filePath}/${filename1}`]);
```

Comment: Excellent solution that saved me a lot of time!

Answer (score 0):

Try using the ID related to input tag instead of button tag.